# ML.Net in VB.Net - DatabaseLoader Requires at least one column error

Tags: vb.net, ml.net

I am trying to train my first model in vb.net but I cannot even launch my application because I get the following error, "System.InvalidOperationException: 'DatabaseLoader requires at least one Column"

Here is my code:

```
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ClientSales;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim commandText As String = "SELECT * from Sales_Quarter_1"
    Dim loader As DatabaseLoader = mlContext.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader()
    Dim dbSource As DatabaseSource = New DatabaseSource(SqlClientFactory.Instance, connectionString, commandText)
    Dim DataView As IDataView = loader.Load(dbSource)
```

Comment: My completely random guess is that you are using `SELECT *`, which is never good anyway, instead of naming the fields you want to `SELECT`.

Comment: Would be a good guess but it is throwing the exception prior to the loader even containing data.

Comment: Have you created any sort of design-time bindings perhaps?

Comment: And being a little blunt it’s really at best pointless, worse counterproductive to post code and then in the comments tell us the error is happening somewhere else